# Json Swift 2 not enter the for

Tags: ios, json, swift

I have this method to read JSON

```
func conecta(){
let myUrl = NSURL(string: "myWebService");let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:myUrl!);
request.HTTPMethod = "POST";

// Compose a query string
let postString = "username=\(userWS)&password=\(passWS)&servidor=\(servidor)"


request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
    data, response, error in
    if error != nil
    {
        print("error=\(error)")
        return
    }

    let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    var err: NSError?
    do{
        let myJSON = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .AllowFragments)




        if let empresas = myJSON["TablaEmp"]!!["item"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
            for empresa in empresas {
                let zcif = empresa["Zcif"] as? String
                let zcccp = empresa["Zcccp"] as? String
                let zfax = empresa["Zfax"] as? String
                let zdocu = empresa["Zdocu"] as? String
                self.arrayEmpresas.append([zcif!, zcccp!, zfax!, zdocu!])
            }
        }


        print("muestro: \(self.arrayEmpresas)")

    }catch { print(error)}
}
task.resume()
}
```

My JSON is anything like that:

```
{"TablaEmp":{"item":[{"Zcif":"123","Zcccp":"456","Zfax":"789","Zdocu":"000"}]}}
```

I have not error, just not enter into my for.

I print my myJSON variable and show perfect JSON, must be this lane I think.

```
 if let empresas = myJSON["TablaEmp"]!!["item"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
```

Thanks

**EDIT**:

Debug

[image]

tablaEmp have "item" but not enter into the function

**EDIT2:**

I tried with another code

```
func conecta(){
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "myWS")!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    let postString = "username=\(userWS)&password=\(passWS)&servidor=\(servidor)"
    request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) { data, response, error in
        guard error == nil && data != nil else {
            print("error=\(error)")
            return
        }

        if let httpStatus = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse where httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {
            print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
            print("response = \(response)")
        }


        let responseString = NSData(data: data!)

        do {
            let jsonDict = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(responseString, options: NSJSONReadingOptions(rawValue: 0)) as? NSDictionary
            if let jsonDict = jsonDict {

                let jsontabla = jsonDict["TablaEmp"]!["item"]
                print("Cargando array")
                for empresa in jsontabla as! [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>] {

                    let zcif = empresa["Zcif"] as? String
                    let zcccp = empresa["Zcccp"] as? String
                    let zfax = empresa["Zfax"] as? String
                    let zdocu = empresa["Zdocu"] as? String
                    self.arrayEmpresas.append([zcif!, zcccp!, zfax!, zdocu!])


                }
                print("muestro: \(self.arrayEmpresas)")




            } else {
                print("No hay valores")
            }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error)
        }

    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Could not cast value of type '__NSCFDictionary' (0x10c0ee178) to 'NSArray' (0x10c0edb88).

Don't understand nothing, my first code must work

**FINAL EDIT**

I found the problem. When my webservice only return one value, the json is like that:

```
{"TablaEmp":{"item":{"othervalues":"500","Zcif":"1111"}}}
```

Without [] and this is the reason that dont work. How can I fix it?

Comment: I have just tested your code with the given data and everything works correctly.

Comment: Try to clean your project and rebuild

Comment: @Sulthan done, but nothing D:

Comment: Add edit 2 with new code

Comment: Are you absolutely sure your JSON has the form you are showing us? Add `print(jsonTabla)` to your new code and let's see if it's really an array of dictionaries.

Comment: Have more values inside JSON but the structure is like that {"TablaEmp":{"item":[{"othervalues":"sssss","Zcif”:”111”},{"othervalues":"sssss","Zcif”:”1111”},{"othervalues":"sssss","Zcif”:”1111”}]}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far you have posted two demo JSONs and two versions of your code. I have tested both and both work. See the following minimal example:

```
// let jsonString = "{\"TablaEmp\":{\"item\":[{\"Zcif\":\"123\",\"Zcccp\":\"456\",\"Zfax\":\"789\",\"Zdocu\":\"000\"}]}}"
let jsonString = "{\"TablaEmp\":{\"item\":[{\"othervalues\":\"sssss\",\"Zcif\":\"111\"},{\"othervalues\":\"sssss\",\"Zcif\":\"111\"},{\"othervalues\":\"sssss\",\"Zcif\":\"111\"}]}}"

let jsonData = jsonString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

let myJSON = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData!, options: .AllowFragments)

// code 1
if let empresas = myJSON["TablaEmp"]!!["item"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
    for empresa in empresas {
        print("Empresa")
    }
}

// code 2
if let jsonDict = myJSON as? NSDictionary {
    let jsontabla = jsonDict["TablaEmp"]!["item"]
    for empresa in jsontabla as! [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>] {
        print("Empresa")
    }
}
```

The only possible explanation is that your JSON has a different form. Don't try to find an error in your code, the code is fine for the JSON you have posted. The problem is that the JSON is different.

One solution to handle both single value and multiple values:

```
let jsonEmpresas = myJSON["TablaEmp"]!!["item"]
let empresas: [[String: AnyObject]]

if let multipleEmpresas = jsonEmpresas as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
    empresas = multipleEmpresas
} else if let singleEmpresa = jsonEmpresas as? [String: AnyObject] {
    empresas = [singleEmpresa]
} else {
    empresas = []
}

// or "for empresa in empresas"
empresas.forEach { empresa in
    let zcif = empresa["Zcif"] as? String
    print(zcif)
}
```

Comment: You right, I found the error. When JSON return 1 value, don't use [] {"TablaEmp":{"item":{"othervalues":"500","Zcif":"1111"}}}

Then, how can I use same JSon method to read JSON with and without []

Comment: @ArisGuimerá I have added one solution how you could handle the different formats.

Comment: Thanks you so much. But last question, i cant use 
let zcif = empresa["Zcif"] as? String
                        let zcccp = empresa["Zcccp"] as? String
                        let zfax = empresa["Zfax"] as? String
                        let zdocu = empresa["Zdocu"] as? String
                        self.arrayEmpresas.append([zcif!, zcccp!, zfax!, zdocu!])


on for each give me this error "cannot subscript a value of type string anyobject with an index of type string"

Comment: @ArisGuimerá See my update,  I have no problem indexing.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you dude. You are the best!